# How to identify webelement using partial attribute of id?

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, textbox

I have to find xpath for a textbox using id attribute. However, a portion of the attribute keeps changing every time I login to the application which I'm automating and the remaining portion remains unchanged. PFB example -

```
Attribute ------> id="StringJob_value_1102199569"
```

Here, the numeric value changes during every login and the portion "StringJob_value" remains unchanged.

Hence, is there any way in selenium to only use the constant portion of the attribute to identify the web element(Text Box)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following xpath:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'StringJob_value_')]
```

Comment: Works, Thanks much!